# How can I get arduino board info by code?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm working on my university final project, and I want to get the SN from the board  in order to send it to the database to identify the board. How can I get the SN by code?

[image: Board Info]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/I0htDvK.png))</sub>

Comment: University final project... in what field? Can you advise where you're getting the Serial Number from? Do you know how to send that to a back-end DB if you've retrieved it?

Comment: hey @stevieb my major is Computer Science... I'am getting the serial number from Tools > get board info... And yes I know how to send it to the back-end... my problem is in how to retrieve it by code...